# Is there any third party platform to get tracks according to BPM

Tags: ios

I am making a music app in which I want to fetch the song according to beat per minute.

I have searched on Spotify but I want some other platform to get songs like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked on Spotify with that you can get the song by BPM with this api.
https://api.spotify.com/v1/recommendations?seed_genres=classical,country&target_tempo=110

```
You can go through with also 
1. Pandora
2. Apple Music
```